# Generate Release notes with Hyperlink Email

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops, release

Generating my release notes works accordingly, and at the end an e-mail gets sent to our inbox with the release notes.

Even though the e-mail states the "associated work items", and the "associated build number", it does not give a hyperlink to the source.

Is there a way to hyperlink the likes the of Bugs, or Work Items that is associated to the release in anyway. Also, the work items. Is there a way to make certain points in Bold or Italic?

My release notes;

```
Release notes for release $defname
Release Number : $($release.name)
Release completed $("{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}" -f [datetime]$release.modifiedOn)

BUILDS
@@BUILDLOOP@@
$($build.definition.name)
BUILD NUMBER: $($build.buildnumber)
BUILD COMPLETED: $("{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}" -f [datetime]$build.finishTime)
SOURCE BRANCH: $($build.sourceBranch)


ASSOCIATED WORK ITEMS
@@WILOOP@@
$($widetail.fields.'System.WorkItemType') $($widetail.id) [Assigned by: $($widetail.fields.'System.AssignedTo'.displayName)] $($widetail.fields.'System.Title')
@@WILOOP@@


ASSOCIATED CHANGE SETS/COMMITS
@@CSLOOP@@
ID $($csdetail.changesetid)$($csdetail.commitid)$($csdetail.id) $($csdetail.comment)
@@CSLOOP@@
@@BUILDLOOP@@
```

My PowerShell;

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\releasenotes.md")
$time = (Get-Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
$release = "release"
$subject = "$release $time"


Send-MailMessage -To "paulbrackenridge@adviserplus.com" -Subject $subject -Body $content -From "noreply@adviserplus.com" -SmtpServer "mailrelay.adviserplus.com.local" -Port 25
```

The outcome;

[image]

Comment: Use `-BodyAsHtml` switch with `Send-MailMessage` and change your links to `<a href />` tags

Comment: I did the -bodyashtml and it worked fine. But the <a href /> does not really work as well.

Comment: What do you mean by does not really work well?  The links came through or not?  Is the not working well part the line breaks?  You likely would need to replace all `"\r?\n"` line breaks with `<br>` html line break tags and maybe some other characters might also have to be replaced.  You can do this with `$content -replace "\r?\n", "<br>"`  and do likewise for other special charcters like < &